# Bootstrap3 fixed column for table

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I checked thrice in SOF, for a solution regarding Bootstrap framework 3.
Even this demo is not working in my system. http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/4XG7T/2/
So, I have a matrix type table that will populate 'n' number of records both horizontally and vertically.
My below code is working fine if there is 5-8 columns, but if there are more than 20 columns the table is collapsed.
In other words, I need something that will keep the header part alone fixed. i.e first row with 'n' number of columns.
How can I achieve that? Could someone redefine my below code.

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="post.php" method="post">
        <div class="table responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.No</th>
            <?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $myloop )) {   ?>
                        <th><?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></th>
            <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
            <?php  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array( $myloop1 )) {   ?>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['author_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row1['author_rating']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

To make it simple I want the below row to be fixed so that I can scroll horizontally and check the records.

```
<tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
<?php  while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $myloop )) {   ?>
    <th><?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></th>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
```

Any help?

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: Your Fiddle is using outdated Bootstrap v3.0.0. Please update to the current version, v3.1.1.

Comment: Please explain what you mean when you say that the table becomes "collapsed".

Comment: cvrebert - I'm using Bootstrap v3.1.1 only

Comment: collapsed - meaning: the width is set to 100% and it is going out of the table if the column increases. got it?

Comment: Should be `table-responsive`, not `table responsive`.

Comment: Then fix your Fiddle to use the right version!